# How do you troubleshooting and tune oracle without oracle diagnosics pack and tuning pack?

Tags: performance, oracle11g, diagnostics, database-tuning

How do you troubleshooting and tune oracle without oracle diagnosics pack and tuning pack?

Comment: See "statspack survival guide

Answer (score 0):

- See "statspack survival guide"
- plus you can still generate AWR reports (uder some circumstances). Use google
- you can also watch v$ views using own sql scripts.

Comment: thanks for your response. We need to investigate the DB activities in the past (3/16/2015) and (3/23/2015), we cannot do statspack snapshot for the past. I tried awr report, it generates empty report because the customer's DB has no diag pack license. V$ view is only works for current, not work for the past (a week or 2 weeks) ago. DBA_HIST_xxxx views are not available for non Diag pack /Tune pack licensed DB.